# Plotting polar plot from a list of values

Tags: python, string, list, plot

I have a list of values in degrees. The values can be between 0 and 360 degrees.

```
values = ['150', '140', '120', '130', '130'...]
```

Each value is a string.

I want to plot the values in a polar plot to show the different wind directions. I'm having problems plotting because I the values are strings. Do I have to convert each values in the list to float or is it possible to plot with values as strings?

I tried to follow this example, but this is with an array. I want to do it with a list with string values:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([10,10,0,0,0,68,90,90,248,240,360])

theta = np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi, 36, endpoint=False)
arad = a*np.pi/180
hist, bins = np.histogram(a,bins=36)

ax = plt.subplot(111,polar = True)
bars = ax.bar(theta, hist)

for r, bar in zip(hist, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.jet(r/10.))
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there an issue with casting the values to floats?

Comment: Yes, you will have to make the values floats; how would you expect matplotlib to interpret the strings? You can use `map(float, values)` to convert easily.

Answer (score 0):

Allow [`numpy.array()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) to convert the strings to floats for you:

```
values = ['150', '140', '120', '130', '130']
a = np.array(values, dtype=float)
```

Or, more succintly

```
a = np.array(['150', '140', '120', '130', '130'], float)
```

---

P.s.: You need to specify a `range` parameter for `np.histogram()`:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(a,range=(0, 360), bins=36)
```